# Difference between .unsubscribe to .take(1)

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I wonder, if there is any difference in performance between using `.take(1)` and `.unsubscribe` when `unsubscribe` is used right after the subscription:

```js
var observable = Rx.Observable.interval(100);
```

First:

```js
var subscription = observable.subscribe(function(value) {
   console.log(value);
}).unsubscribe();
```

Second:

```js
var subscription = observable.take(1).subscribe(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Any ideas of it makes any different regard the performance?

Comment: `var subscription = observable.subscribe({function A}).unsubscribe();` will not work as expected incase funcation A will be called after javascrit will finish excute this line. So insted of getting only one value, you will get zero values. It is recommneded to subscribe manually and use take(..) or other methods like take that deals with the subscription for you.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Each serves a different purpose so it's hard to compare them.

In general if you take this source:

```
const source = range(1,3);
```

... and consume it with `subscribe()` followed immediately by `unsubscribe()`:

```
source.subscribe(
  console.log,
  undefined, 
  () => console.log('complete')
).unsubscribe();
```

... then all values from `source` are going to be emitted even though we called `unsubscribe()` right after subscribing. This is because the code is still strictly sequential (synchronous) and the `source` is a cold Observable.

```
1
2
3
complete
```

Btw, try adding `delay(0)` operator to make `source.pipe(delay(0)).subscribe(...).unsubscribe()`. This makes emitting values asynchronous using an actual `setTimeout()` call and for this reason `unsubscribe()` is called before any `next` handlers and is discarded immediately.

In other words `unsubscribe()` let's you stop receiving values anytime. Even when the source hasn't emitted any value (we never receive any complete notification).

Using `take()` operator limits the chain to only emit a specific number of values.

```
source.pipe(
  take(1),
)
.subscribe(
  console.log,
  undefined,
  () => console.log('complete')
);
```

This just emits a single value and completes:

```
1
complete
```

Even if you add `.unsubscribe()` the result would be the same.

See live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tbu5kb

So `take()` is an operator while `unsubscribe()` is a method on a [`Subscription`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscription.ts) object. These two things are often interchangeable but they never fully substitute each other.

Jan 2019: Updated for RxJS 6

Comment: hi @martin does take(1) do unsubscription? If I add take(1), do I have to call unsubscribe again? Thanks

Comment: @fifth No, you don't. When the chain completes it recursively calls all dispose handlers so you don't need to call `unsubscribe` yourself.

Comment: fifth, @martin - could you make a question and answer from these two comments? I actually looked for this specific question ('does take-1 do unsubscribe?') and got into this question accidentaly. Judging from the unusually high amount of upvotes on your comments, other people seem to agree ;) Or at least add/interleve it into the current Q&A in some visible way. The fact that take-X (or, any 'completion' of a stream) do unsubscribe is really important, and I can't find any Q&A that would touch that matter and give definitive and clear answer like martin's comment here.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl It calls unsubscribe if you see the source code. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/take.ts#L95

Comment: Be careful, if by any reason it doesn't take one (or any number of count) it doesn't unsubscribe.

Answer (score 65):

> Just keep in mind that *take(1)* still doesn’t unsubscribe when
> component is being destroyed. The subscription remains active until
> first value is emitted no matter if component is active or destroyed.
> So if we do something more crazy, like accessing the DOM, in our
> subscription — we might end up with an error in the console.

https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0

Comment: and what is the solution for unsubscribe?
dont use take, and replace it with takeUntil(this.destroyable$), this.destroyable$ is subject in separate component which will next on ngOnDestroy

Comment: @pinarella that linked article has several potential solutions, including the most common approaches for unsubscribing when a component is destroyed. If you need help for a specific solution then create a question and post full details.