# How to Stop observable.timer in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I am implementing the following functions in Angular2's Component:

```
export class MypageEditComponent {

  ngOnInit() {
    this.timer = Observable.timer(100, 100);
    this.timer.subscribe(t => {
      this.setFormData();
  }


  private setFormData() {
    this.editUserAcountType = this.authStore.registerInfo.account_type;
    this.editAddress = this.authStore.registerInfo.email;
    this.editUserName = this.authStore.registerInfo.username;
  }
}
```

I want to stop the repeat of `Observable.timer` once the value is correctly stored with `setFormData()`.

But do not know how, please tell me.

Comment: So you want to stop it after executing once? Or are you waiting for `this.authStore.registerInfo` data to be set somewhere so you need to keep calling `setFormData` until the data arrives?

Comment: If you know how much time it takes to receive the data, why don't you use an operator like delay.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a good idea to do that. If you give more information about what you're trying to achieve, maybe we might point another direction to handle your problem

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There're are basically two ways:

- call `unsubscribe()` on the Subscription object returned from the `subscribe()` call .
- use an operator

To just `unsubscribe` you could do it like this.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = timer(100, 100).subscribe(t => {
    this.setFormData();
  });
}

private setFormData() {
  ...
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Or you can use Subject to complete the Observable via `takeUntil()` operator:

```
this.subject = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  timer(100, 100).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.subject),
  ).subscribe(t => this.setFormData());
}

private setFormData() {
  ...
  this.subject.next();
}
```

Have a look these as well:

- [Difference between .unsubscribe to .take(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563065/difference-between-unsubscribe-to-take1/40564340#40564340)
- [RxJS: takeUntil() Angular component's ngOnDestroy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490265/rxjs-takeuntil-angular2-components-ngondestroy/42493315#42493315)

Jan 2019: Updated for RxJS 6

Comment: I didn't know we could unsubscribe from within the subscription block. Good to know.

Answer (score 14):

you can use `unsubscribe` method when you want to stop timer observable like this

```
this.timer = Observable.timer(100, 100);
this.subscription = this.timer.subscribe(t => {
    this.setFormData();
});

.............
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: why so many downvotes  ? is this answer wrong ? even answer of @martin having same code as i posted

Comment: Yes. `unsubscribe` is called on a `Subscription`, not on an `Observable`.

Comment: okii but answer does't provide any wrong information right ? afterall you have to use unsubscribe method right ? than why downvote ?

Comment: i know code is correct but not different i think, still thanks for let me know i have edited my answer

Comment: Now that you've edited it, it's correct. The unedited code was incorrect.

Comment: hmm @cartant may be you are right, i just post the code before testing, i think that is my mistake

Answer (score 3):

A nuance which previous answers haven't really covered is that there is no need to *stop* an observable timer/interval - at least not by interacting with the observable or the timer itself.

*I found myself here because I was setting up an observable using a timer in a HostedService's start method, and in the stop method it **seemed** like I should be stopping it, or disposing of something surely? - well... no. The observable timer does not need to be stopped or disposed in this way, only the subscriptions, and this is why...*

Observable timers and intervals are examples of *cold streams* (though they appear to behave as hot).  They are passive not active, they do not produce data till subscribed to, and stop producing data when no subscribers.  Therefore, disposal of all subscriptions should be all that's required to stop the timer producing data.

More info here... [http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html]

Answer (score -1):

xD did you know you can make it a promise?

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

timer(1000).toPromise().then(res => {
      //code here  
})
```

no need to deal with unsubscribe.

Answer (score -2):

-- workaround

```
setTimeout(() => observable.next(null) , 2000);
```